# hw_lock_bit_nopreempt() kernel panic M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: big-sur, kernel-panic, apple-silicon

My M1 Macbook Pro has constant kernel panics with some variation of:

`panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffe0017ae7a44): "hw_lock_bit_nopreempt(): timed out (0xfffffdf036ef019c)"`

I cannot figure out what the cause is. Usually the crash report will include information about the last run kext to identify the faulty software but the crash reports I get don't have any kext information.

Anybody know what the cause might be?

Machine info:

- macOS Big Sur 11.6
- MacBookPro 13-inch M1 2020
- 16GB RAM

Connected Peripherals:

- Dell 38" monitor via USB-C with Power Delivery
- ORICO USB 3 4 port hub
- Logitech M720 wireless mouse (via USB receiver)
- Pok3r mechanical keyboard

Crash Report

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffe0017ae7a44): "hw_lock_bit_nopreempt(): timed out (0xfffffdf036ef019c)"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20G165
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:20 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 6304A06696A657F4CF48CC569B129642
Kernel UUID: DA16DC13-5845-3638-9BB4-B14F9AC08E55
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.140.2
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000fe6c000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0016e70000
Kernel slide:      0x00000000109b4000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe00179b8000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe0017a84000
mach_absolute_time: 0x14dfabf878e
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x617bfb89 0x0001f023
  Sleep   : 0x617f2184 0x0008ca8c
  Wake    : 0x617f24d6 0x0009d58f
  Calendar: 0x617f3eb7 0x0009ccd1

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d50
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf5688
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d50
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d50
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d54
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d54
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d54
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0017bf6d54
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: 920665 - First lock was acquired at PC=0xfffffe00182a9214, LR=0xfffffe0017a8bfc4
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
Panic occurred while attempting to lock PAI 920665 (0xe3fffdf20b1907b1):
PTEP (0xfffffdf0d6e84bd0) is a User CPU mapping (pmap: 0xfffffdf03742de20)
PTEP (0xfffffdf0d6e84bb8) is a User CPU mapping (pmap: 0xfffffdf03742de20)
PTEP (0xfffffdf0d6e84ba0) is a User CPU mapping (pmap: 0xfffffdf03742de20)

...<bunch more PTEP lines
```

Comment: As a starting point, knowing that macOS has a history of latent bugs that are triggered by peripherals, try running first without your ORICO hub and see if the panics go away. If not, take your external display out of the equation. Finally, remove all of your other peripherals. Please let us know your results either way.

Comment: Any clue what “hw_lock_bit_nopreempt“ might be referring to? I just got another kernel panic with that same message without the Orico USB Hub. I had another kernel panic issue before with a different usb wireless mouse receiver and the it had “usb” in the kernel panic dump.

Comment: I did not have this issue with my previous Intel MacBook Pro with all the same attached peripherals

Comment: `hw_lock_bit_nopreempt()` is a low-level function used by the macOS virtual memory system. The particular panic signature that you are experiencing is way too generic to be useful to root-cause your exact issue. A typical debugging scenario would involve setting up an identical system (or rack of systems) to reproduce the panic with debug-variant kernels and coredumps enabled, gathering the resultant core dump, and analyzing it in `lldb`. Because you are unlikely to do that, we are using large hammers to test particular classes of possible root cause (e.g., device driver bugs).

Comment: Just because you didn't have this issue with a previous version of the product carrying the same name as your current product doesn't mean much. Any hardware differences between product generations can introduce subtle bugs. This is even more true when you are switching entire processing architectures (Intel -> Apple Silicon). Bugs are expected and users become inadvertent QA engineers. Chalk this one up to helping your other fellow users who experience the same panic and *haven't* had the wherewithal to post at StackExchange! :-)

Comment: Any updates on this or did the issue get resolved?

Comment: No updates. I just restart my laptop more frequently to avoid the issue.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of running without the hub for a while?

Comment: Yeah the only thing I didn't try was running without the external monitor (over USB-C connection which has a built in hub). I'm using this laptop for work and using this laptop without the external monitor would have seriously affected my work flow.
I may have a chance to try it out without the external monitor when work slows down at the end of December